# Facebook App page '144534545691657/feed' return only empty data

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I made a simple test Page in the Facebook which looks OK. I have provided the extended permission of read_stream and manage_pages. I am using Facebook SDK  6.0.10 and in code it connects to the Page correctly by providing the basic page information like name, category etc. However in the code;

I generated the authentication code from facebook correctly.

```
  var fb1 = new FacebookClient("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");

  //Page info is comming correclty.
  dynamic PageInfo = fb1.Get("144534545691657");
```

//Here no feed/statuses/posts and only empty data is returned.
//And also the same behavior exist if i access it from Graph APi Explorer on Facebook.

```
  dynamic feed = fb1.Get("144534545691657/feed");
```

[image is for your reference showing the Graph Explorer view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CfGQT.png)

I have few posts that have already posted on my Page. 
How i can get the feed details?

Comment: What are you doing? 144534545691657 is not a page ID - is that your app ID? Apps don't have a usable feed connection

Comment: Yes it is my AppID. So I just want to read the post of my page which is created as an App. How will i achieve this?

Comment: OR How to get the page Posts data. I could not find the way to have a Page whose posts can be fetched with FacebookSDK. Please help...

Comment: 'page which is created as an app' doesn't make any sense - any Facebook Page can have its posts read via the API, and you can use an app access token for this if there are no demographic restrictions on the page - you have the API call correct, but you're asking for the feed of an app, not the feed of the page

Comment: Thanks for your update. What i got from your good reply is i have to get the PageID similarly like we have userId and then get the feed/posts. At this time i am trying to get the feed through AppID which you are saying the invalid way. OK I will try it and then come back to you. Please tell me if i am wrong.

Comment: Thanks.............For..........Your..........good.............Help.

Comment: It is done. Actually i was giving AppID/feed as you mentioned. Now i checked it and found the PageID/feed. Feeds are now coming :)